# How update object with relation data in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have used the Entity Framework Core and update some object with relation to another object.

I have a following entities:

Client:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public List<ClientScope> Scopes { get; set; }
}
```

ClientScope:

```
public class ClientScope
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Scope { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
  }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>((Action<EntityTypeBuilder<Client>>) (client =>
      {
        client.ToTable<Client>(storeOptions.Client);
        client.HasKey((Expression<Func<Client, object>>) (x => (object) x.Id));
        client.Property<string>((Expression<Func<Client, string>>) (x => x.ClientId)).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired(true);
        client.HasIndex((Expression<Func<Client, object>>) (x => x.ClientId)).IsUnique(true);
        client.HasMany<ClientScope>((Expression<Func<Client, IEnumerable<ClientScope>>>) (x => x.AllowedScopes)).WithOne((Expression<Func<ClientScope, Client>>) (x => x.Client)).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
      }));

modelBuilder.Entity<ClientScope>((Action<EntityTypeBuilder<ClientScope>>) (scope =>
      {
        scope.ToTable<ClientScope>(storeOptions.ClientScopes);
        scope.Property<string>((Expression<Func<ClientScope, string>>) (x => x.Scope)).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired(true);
      }));
```

I would like update the `ClientScope` for specific `Client.Id` for example Id = 1.

I have tried use this way:

```
public void UpdateClientScope(ClientScope scope){

_dbContext.ClientScope.Update(scope);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

var scope = new ClientScope() { Client = new Client{Id = 1}, Id = 1, Scope = "Test Scope" }
UpdateClientScope(scope);
```

But this way try to update the `Client` as well. I want to update only ClientScope and specify ClientId which it is stored on my form.

What is the best way how update `ClientScope` above?

I have tried to implement the `BaseRepository` which I want to implement for every entity something like this:

```
public class BaseRepository<TDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IBaseRepository<TDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
        where TEntity : class
        where TDbContext : DbContext
{
 public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Table => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
 
private readonly TDbContext _dbContext;

public BaseRepository(TDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
      
public virtual async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            Table.Update(entity);

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity;
        }
}
```

How can I correctly specify the `update` method for entities like this?

Comment: Updating the disconnected entity with relations cannot be done with naïve generic approach which works only for simple entities w/o navigation properties.

Comment: Please, what do you mean with disconnected entities?

Comment: The ones that are not retrieved/tracked by the context. Like your `var scope = new ClientScope() { Client = new Client{Id = 1}, Id = 1, Scope = "Test Scope" }`. Both `scope` and `scope.Client` are disconnected. As opposed to `var scope = _dbContext.ClientScope.Include(x => x.Client).FirstOrDefault(...);`. In the later case EF knows that `scope` and `scope.Client` exists in database, in former case it has absolutely no idea what they are, hence you have to properly attach them manually.

Comment: And unfortunately currently there is no single method which works for all scenarios. See [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) topic under **Saving Data** section of the documentation - it's empty :(

Comment: Thank you Ivan - can you please paste some example - how do you mean attach manually?

Comment: Well, in you concrete case (the `UpdateClientScope` method), it would be enough to include `_dbContext.Attach(scope.Client);` before calling `_dbContext.ClientScope.Update(scope);`

Comment: OK, and is it correct - that I have on line scope.Client => only Client {Id = 1} - ot is it necessary have whole object of Client?

Comment: The technique is called *stub* entity and should work as soon as the context is short lived and used just for the operation in question. If there are multiple calls to the same context instance, the things can get messed up. Another way in scenario like this is to have explicit FK property, and pass scope with `Client` set to `null` and `ClientId` set to `1`.

Comment: Ivan please, post your ideas as an answer - this is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you never plan to add or modify a related entity via your repository methods you can simply set all other entities' state to `EntityState.Unchanged`, e.g.:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    Table.Update(entity);

    foreach( var entry in _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries() )
    {
        if( entry.Entity != entity )
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
    }

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entity;
}
```

Alternatively, attach related entities as unchanged before calling the repo method(s).  Perhaps create a repo method to return such an entity:

```
public TEntity GetEntityPlaceholder( int id )
{
    var entity = new TEntity() { Id = id };
    _dbContext.Attach( entity );
    return entity;
}
```

I prefer having the FK properties available, myself:

```
public class ClientScope
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Scope { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
    // FK, use [ForeignKey( "Client" )] if you wish
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}

// or use FluentAPI
modelBuilder.Entity<ClientScope>()
    .HasRequired( cs => cs.Client )
    .WithMany( c => c.Scopes )
    // specify foreign key
    .HasForeignKey( cs => cs.ClientId );

// now can specify a client by setting the ClientId property
var scope = new ClientScope() 
{ 
    ClientId = 1, 
    Id = 1, 
    Scope = "Test Scope",
}
UpdateClientScope(scope);
```

Comment: Moho - interesting idea - what do you mean having the FK properies available - how do you do updating like above? Thank you.

Comment: Create an `int ClientId { get; set; }` property and configure its use as the `Client`'s FK property either via the `ForeignKeyAttribute` or FluentAPI.  Then you simply set the `ClientId` property with the client's ID instead of having to instantiate and attach a `Client` entity object

Comment: I love your answer - please can you put your modified model like you mentioned in previous comment and how these model structure update? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments (thanks, Ivan), EF needs to 'know about' the object you want to update.

Sorry, I don't have anything to hand to test this with, but your UpdateClientScope method should look something like this:

```
public void UpdateClientScope(ClientScope scope){

// Get the existing object from the DB
ClientScope dbScope = _dbContext.ClientScope.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == scope.Id);

// Test it was in DB
if (dbScope != null)
{
  // Update the database object
  dbScope.Scope = scope.Scope;
  dbScope.Client = scope.Client;

  // SaveChanges works on dbScope
  _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
  // Object not found, some error processing
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I  do  not  understand  where is  a problem ?  through  DBContext  object  you  can reach  any  class  object than object's property,  than  just  change a  value of property with  simple  assign  operator  and  just  DbContext.SaveChanges()  your  changes  will be updated in Database  column  with no problem at all. If you  want  separate Update()  method for  changes you  can do it with couple  of  code lines  or  more complex  way with  C# Reflection  possibility but i can't imagine why  would you need  this ?!  If  i missed  something  tell me more. Good luck !!!!

Comment: You can imagine - I create a new Client with set of properties but if I want to update only ClientScope and I want to specify only Client.Id and I want to update only ClientScope but the object Client will be updated as well and all properties of Client is set to default values. How can I specify that I want to update only ClientScope - not Client? :)

Comment: Well  i think  you  model building  is not  correct  in Client model  class  you have declared List  generic  and  with ClientScope inside  generic  then in ClientScope model class  you have  declared  Client  model instance  to be  honest  i did not  understand  why  did you linked  both  objects in  both model  and  very  different  way ?  Why  ClientScope is  List object ?  Why  do you  need  List object what is a purpose ?  and in ClientScope model  Client model  what  is  doing there ?

Comment: I've updated my post with current settings in OnModelCreating method. For one client could be more clientscopes - for this purpose it probable use List with ClientScope. ClientScope must be connected with one Client. Feel free to paste your idea of model. Thank you.

Comment: Just   make  two distinct models and  that's  it !   You have said  that  when you  want to update  ClientScope  same  time you you do not want  to  update Client model isn't it ?  And here  we go  just  create  two separate  class models  and everything  will be ok.  If  anyway  you want  that  Client model and ClientScope model should have  similar property for joining  data  later.  You can do it in SQL Server(or any  DB  you are using).  Either  way  i  do not see a purpose  for dependency on  property level.

Comment: You mean - create separate models and create foreign key and etc. out of model - for examle on sql management studio manually?

Comment: It's your  choice  how would use  Entity Framework  Code First  or  Database First  ?!  What you need is  better  fetch  Entity Framework  Core  features  and in general enterprise application requirements and  design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

i think your entities false because your ClientScope has not clientId (Foreign Key).

public string ClientId { get; set; }

Comment: I have created the Foreign Key in OnModelCreating section - that I don't paste here - my failt sorry. And ClientId is not primary key - just unique identitfier for Client.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).